# Woocommerce if bought more than different one product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

In the final step of the checkout, i would to show a button ONLY if there are 2 or more DIFFERENTE products, so i was trying to figure a way to count if there was indeed 2 or more, i tried something like this:

```
if (sizeof(WC()->cart->get_cart()) != 1) {
echo '<a class="button emptycart" href="example-link">Sample-Text</a>';
}
```

Obviously with no luck. I tried doing like different cases when knowing the product id, but even when i only have 5, there would be like 25 if statements to accomplish this task, something like:

```
if ( woocommerce_customer_bought_product( $email, $current_user->ID, '5898' )) && ( woocommerce_customer_bought_product( $email, $current_user->ID, '5936' )){
echo '<a style="float: right; position: relative;margin-top: -35px;" class="button emptycart" href="SAMPLE">BUY</a>';
}elseif ( woocommerce_customer_bought_product( $email, $current_user->ID, '5935' )) && ( woocommerce_customer_bought_product( $email, $current_user->ID, '5937' )){
echo '<a class="button emptycart" href="SAMPLE">BUY</a>';
}
```

And so on... so any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

add_action( 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout', 'insert_empty_cart_button' );

`function insert_empty_cart_button() {`

```
//array to store unique ids of the product
$unique_product_array=array();

    // Cycle through each product in the cart
    foreach( WC()->cart->cart_contents as $prod_in_cart ) {
        // Get the Variation or Product ID
        $prod_id = ( isset( $prod_in_cart['variation_id'] ) && $prod_in_cart['variation_id'] != 0 ) ? $prod_in_cart['variation_id'] : $prod_in_cart['product_id'];

        // Check if the product already exist in array
        if( in_array($prod_id,$unique_product_array) {
    array_push($unique_product_array,$prod_id);
        }
    }

//check the number of unique products in the product array
if(count($unique_product_array)>1) {
    echo '<a class="button emptycart" href="example-link">Sample-Text</a>';
}
}
```

`}?>`

This code might help you to achieve your purpose. Just add it to appropriate hook where you require. Here i have added it on 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout' which will also work.

Comment: Could you help me to make it act like, if there is only 1 product with certain id do that, and then if there are multiple, check that there are more than one? @WisdmLabs please..

Comment: I think its because you looking into cart, but at thank you page is where i want to show the button so you should be looking into order instead.